# Azure AD B2C Custom Policy for Custom Identity Server 3 IDP

Tags: identityserver3, azure-ad-b2c, idp

I have uploaded the custom policy for custom IDP which is using Identity Server 3 and OpenId to communicate.

I am passing secret key as the cryptographic key for TrustFrameWorkExtensions.xml file but I am getting error policy doesn't contain the cryptographic key client_secret_ correlation ID, Any help as I am stuck with this error message ?

I followed this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom

Comment: Is this occurring when you uploaded the extension file or when you run the custom policy?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett I am getting this error when i run the custom policy after uploading the Frameworkextension file.

Comment: Hi @Renu. Can you add the technical profile to the above question please? Have you included `<Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_IdentityServerSecret" />` or similar in the technical profile?

Comment: Hi @Renu. Did you have any latest update for this?